# Python: Find out what method on derived class called base class method

Tags: python

Hope the title isn't to confusing wasn't sure how I should put it. I wonder if it's possible for the base class to know which method of the derived class called one of it's methods.

Example:

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = {}

    def output(self, s):
        method_that_called_me = #is it possible?
        self.output[method_that_called_me] = s

class Public(Controller):
    def about_us(self):
        self.output('Damn good coffee!')

    def contact(self):
        self.output('contact me')
```

So is it possible for the output method to know which method from the Public class called it?

Comment: what is `output` meant to be ? A `dict` or a `method` ?

Comment: dict, did I do something weird? I am new to Python.

Comment: ~unutbu explained what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a somewhat magical way to do what you are looking for using introspection on the call stack. But that isn't portable since not all implementations of Python have the necessary functions. It's probably not a good design decision to use introspection either.

Better, I think, to be explicit:

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._output = {}

    def output(self, s, caller):
        method_that_called_me = caller.__name__
        self._output[method_that_called_me] = s

class Public(Controller):
    def about_us(self):
        self.output('Damn good coffee!',self.about_us)

    def contact(self):
        self.output('contact me',self.contact)
```

PS. Note that you have `self.output` as both a `dict` and a `method`. I've altered it so `self._output` is a `dict`, and `self.output` is the method.

PPS. Just to show you what I was referring to by magical introspection:

```
import traceback

class Controller(object):
    def output_method(self, s):
        (filename,line_number,function_name,text)=traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
        method_that_called_me = function_name
        self.output[method_that_called_me] = s
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer I got the same advice from the Python IRC channel. That it's better to be explicit. aha, thanks for your PS didn't see that.

Comment: Awesome, each time I refresh there is even more good information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/inspect-stack.html).

```
import inspect
frame = inspect.currentframe()
method_that_called_me = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1][3]
```

where `method_that_called_me` will be a string. The `1` is for the direct caller, the `3` the position of the function name in the 'frame record'

Comment: while this technically answers the question, the right answer is "be explicit". If you need to revert to hacks using the inspect module you're doing something very wrong (or you shouldn't need to ask in the first place)